# Lock action vote after a deadline time, unlock when editing the instance voted in Django

Tags: python, django

As I say in the title, I want to allow a user to vote on an instance named, `Course` and lock the vote after *72 hours* or *3 days* (In my example, it will be 2 minutes). Where I get stuck is that I want to allow users to edit vote if the course has been edited by its owner. When a course being edited, all its votes must be unlocked.

> How bad today is, All the logic are gone, I can't think anymore, already tear off multiple sheets of paper!

So far, I can lock a vote, I mean I think I lock it.

```
''' stuff '''
if vote:
    NOW = datetime.datetime.now()
    DEADLINE = 2 # minutes
    if (NOW - course.date_edited).total_seconds() < (DEADLINE * 60):
        vote.amount = amount
        vote.save()
 else:
     vote = Vote.objects.create(
        user = user,
        amount = amount,
        content_object = course,
     )
```

`date_edited` for the the 2 models are set to `auto_now_add = True` in db

I think another approach is to edit the date for all the votes for a course when editing it, like:

```
   course.votes.all().update(date_voted=....) # I am not sure
```

let me know how to do it. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set `auto_now=True` for `date_voted` field and add `date_vote_created` with `auto_now_add=True`. And in your view check if course has been changed after this date also:

```
if vote:
    NOW = datetime.datetime.now()
    DEADLINE = 2 # minutes
    if course.date_edited > vote.date_voted or (NOW - vote.date_vote_created).total_seconds() < (DEADLINE * 60):
        vote.amount = amount
        vote.save()
```

**UPD**

To unlock vote for two minutes after course has been changed you can reset `date_vote_created` in separate `if` blocks.

```
if vote:
    NOW = datetime.datetime.now()
    DEADLINE = 2 # minutes
    if course.date_edited > vote.date_voted:
        vote.date_vote_created = NOW
        vote.save()
    if course.date_edited > vote.date_voted or (NOW - vote.date_vote_created).total_seconds() < (DEADLINE * 60): 
        vote.amount = amount
        vote.save()
```

**UPD #2**

```
if course.date_edited > vote.date_voted:
    vote.amount = amount
    vote.date_vote_created = NOW
    vote.save()
elif (NOW - vote.date_vote_created).total_seconds() < (DEADLINE * 60): 
    vote.amount = amount
    vote.save()
else:
    print("Vote locked")
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I want to make sure: `date_voted` will remain the same as the `date` added when creating the object? is that correct?

Comment: @Lemayzeur my initial idea was that you can use only  `date_voted` field, which should be set during creation and updating `vote` object. But now I think you also need `date_vote_create` to check if vote locked or not:) Look at updated answer. Is it what you are looking for?

Comment: Ok! almost works, what I want is when editing the course, the user has the same `deadline time` 2 minutes after his first vote on the course edited to get hist vote locked... with your example, after the edit, the user can vote once, and after vote is locked, whereas I need to give the user another 2 minutes

Comment: @Lemayzeur you can reset `date_vote_created` if course has been changed. See example in update. Suppose it will work. In this case `date_vote_created` should be renamed to something like `date_lock_start`.

Comment: perfect, it will also work with `if` `elif` and `else` statement since I want to print `Vote locked after 2 minutes` in `else` block. You can also do this with less code. I will edit your answer and accept it. thank you